# How can I delete an artist or album in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

I made the mistake of importing a Japanese music album in Rhythmbox, and now it is displaying the track titles in Japanese instead of using the English titles that are the names of the track files. I have since added other Japanese albums without importing, just by putting the album folder in ~/music, and I can create a playlist with the album name and get the English titles that way. I tried to delete the folder in question and recopy it, but when I do, it automatically lists the titles in Japanese again. I am assuming that deleting the album or artist would fix my problem, but there is no clear way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Rythmbox, like most players, reads and uses [ID3 tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) (metadata) in the audio files and presents that in the library view instead of the files names.

Renaming the files doesn't change the metadata.

**In Rythmbox you have the option to edit the files properties**: Right-click on the track and select Properties. Edit can be made in the window as shown below, kindly provided by [Elder Geek](https://askubuntu.com/users/225694/elder-geek). Changes will be saved when closed.

[image]

Alternatively, **you can edit the files' metadata directly**.
**EasyTag** (pictured below) is a tag editor available in Ubuntu repositories:

```
sudo apt install easytag
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The auto-populating of the track info is likely coming from the [last.fm](http://www.last.fm/api) extension in RythmBox. You should be able  disable it by clearing the checkbox for it. You'll find it under Tools -> Plugins

[image]

You can disable it and test by editing the offending tracks and checking to see if the changes persist.

To  the best of my knowledge it is not possible to delete an artist or album in Rythmbox. Since you do have complete control over tracks though, what you CAN do is to edit specific tracks Properties by right clicking on the track and selecting Properties. You can edit your corrections into the window as shown below.

[image: RythmboxProps]

Source: Testing